# C library in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem using a C library in C++.
I fear that the solution is very easy but I am to stupid to get it.

The library defines the function like this:

```
CAENHVLIB_API CAENHVRESULT  CAENHV_GetChName(int handle, ushort slot, 
   ushort ChNum, const ushort *ChList, char (*ChNameList)[MAX_CH_NAME]);
```

In the example it is called like this:

```
char  (*listNameCh)[MAX_CH_NAME];
// ... leaving out the other lines since they are not the problem ...
listNameCh = malloc(MAX_CHANNELS*MAX_CH_NAME);
ret = CAENHV_GetChName(handle, slot, NrOfCh, listaCh, listNameCh);
```

So now the problem. In C++ I am not able to use the malloc(MAX_CHANNELS * MAX_CH_NAME) because I cant cast it correctly. It works with "-fpermissive"-Flag but I would like to do it without such a hack.

Somebody has an idea how to get around this?

Cheers

Comment: _"because I cant cast it correctly"_ What did you actually try to cast it?

Comment: you have to cast it manually. In the code sample you provided, you didn't try to cast it.

Comment: Yes, I removed the casting in the post because I was trying it wrong. Didn't use C or C++ for some time and got a bit rusty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can probably cast it correctly to avoid the `-fpermissive`.

One one level this isn't a hack - C and C++ have different rules for implicit casting here. If you insist on writing C in C++, you'll need the occasional cast to make it work.

On another level, the problem is that you're writing C and compiling it as C++. It would be better to either

1. re-write it as good, idiomatic C++. You should be able to use `std::array<char[MAX_CH_NAME], MAX_CHANNELS>` and it will take care of the allocation for you

   - or you can use `std::vector<char[MAX_CH_NAME]>` similarly if you want to re-size it
2. re-write it as less-good C++, with explicit new/delete instead of malloc/free (new expressions are strongly-typed and don't need casting)
3. write your C code in a C-language module, exposing some sane interface, and then call it from C++

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `malloc` or `new`. If you use `malloc`, you have to cast the returned value. If you use `new`, you don't have to cast.

```
listNameCh = (char (*)[MAX_CH_NAME])malloc(MAX_CHANNELS*MAX_CH_NAME);
```

or

```
listNameCh = new char[MAX_CHANNELS][MAX_CH_NAME];
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly that way. I forgot the brackets around the star in "(char (*)[MAX_CHANNELS])" (I had "(char*[MAX_CHANNELS])"). A bit to rusty in programming C/C++ and to much time pressure.